# Laravel custom verification notification error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to update the verification email notification in Laravel. I tried to generate verification link in AppServiceProvider then passed the link to a notification class but later it gave me an error that 'undefined property ::$view'.

AppServiceProvider

```
/**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        VerifyEmail::toMailUsing(function ($notifiable) {
             $verificationUrl = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
                'verification.verify',
                Carbon::now()->addMinutes(config('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
                [
                    'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                    'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
                ]
            );

            return new EmailVerification($verificationUrl);
        });
    }
```

VerificationEmail

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class EmailVerification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    public $verificationUrl;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($verificationUrl)
    {
        $this->verificationUrl = $verificationUrl;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $verificationUrl = $this->verificationUrl;

        return (new MailMessage)
                        ->subject('Please verify your email')
                        ->markdown('emails.verification', ['url' => $verificationUrl]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Associated markdown view to the Notification.

```
@component('mail::message')
# Email verification - {{ config('app.name') }}

Your registration on our application <b> {{ config('app.name') }} </b> was successfull. Kindly click the button below to verify your email address.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => $url])
Verify Email
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

The error I'm receiving

**
ErrorException
Undefined property: App\Notifications\EmailVerification::$view
**

[image: Actual error message]

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: Laravel 7.2 and tried to customise the verification email notification

Comment: I have checked on my environment. It works as normal. I hope you generate the notification class as "php artisan make:notification EmailVerification --markdown=verification" and then use "\Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail::toMailUsing()" function.

Comment: Still the same issue, I'm passing the URL as public property in notification class and everything is fine but not going through, However, If I directly write the notification in AppServiceProvider then it works as normal but I want to do it separately. Updated question with error screenshot.

Comment: How are you using this separately in your controller? As per your question you override the verify mail function in the app service provider. so next time whenever the user is registered then your custom email will send to the user to verify his/her email. But where are you using this separately in your controller?

Comment: If I do this in AppServiceProvide it is working else not.

            return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject('Please verify your email')
                    ->action('Verify Email', $verificationUrl);

Comment: Ok. So now your question is you have "EmailVerification" notification and you want to use it in custom place(like any controller) and want to hit the email functionality?

Comment: No. I want to overwrite Laravel email verification notification. So I created the Notification class and then passed the verification URL from AppServiceProvider and then access that URL in notification and pass it to markdown view and then send custom notification. You can see my codes, I did everything but I see Undefined property ::$view error.

Comment: Well, I did not see any kind of error on my side.

Comment: Your codes are the same as mine and working fine??

Comment: Kind of. But I use the full namespace. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61042252/laravel-custom-verification-notification-error?noredirect=1#comment107995500_61042252

Comment: One more thing, If I return $verificationUrl on Appserviceprovide it gives me error "trying to get property VIEW of non-object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very well explained in this tutorial.
https://brabeum.com/2019/10/customise-the-laravel-user-verification-email/

You should first override in your user model the default function that send the notification when the user register.

/app/User.php

```
/**
 * Override the default function that send a notification to verify
 * the email after a new user register.
 *
 */
  public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
  {
     $this->notify(new Notifications\UserVerificationEmail);
  }
```

Then to create a custom notification:

/app/Notifications/EmailVerification.php.

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class UserVerificationEmail extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Please verify your email address')
        ->markdown(
            'emails.userverify', 
            [
               'url' => $this->verificationUrl($notifiable),
               'notifiable' => $notifiable,
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    /*
   * Build the verification URL
   *
   * @return URL
   */
   protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
   {
      return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
         'verification.verify',
         Carbon::now()->addMinutes(
            Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
              [
                'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
              ]     
         ); 
   }
}
```

and then the mailable template:

/resources/views/emails/userverify.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
# Welcome {{ $notifiable->name }}

Before you can use this tutorial system you must verify your email address.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => $url])
Brabeum Verify Email Address Tutorial
@endcomponent

If you did not create an account, no further action is required.
Thanks,

{{ config('app.name') }} Team

@component('mail::subcopy')
If you’re having trouble clicking the "Verify Email Address" button, copy and paste the URL below into your web browser: {{ $url }} 
@endcomponent

@endcomponent
```

Comment: Hello, I am using a Laravel 9 and get this error message: Call to a member function sendEmailVerificationNotification() on null